# Restart jQuery Countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I'm currently working on a jQuery plugin.

```
http://plugins.jquery.com/kbw.countdown/
```

I want to restart the counter when it reaches 00:00:00 time.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var austDay = new Date();
    austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 00);
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: '+5s'});
    $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());  
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your target times and initialize with an expiry event like this:

```
 $('#noon-countdown').countdown({until: getNoonCountDown(),
        serverSync: serverTime, format: 'HMS',
        onExpiry: function() {
            $(this).countdown('change', {until: getNoonCountDown()});
        }});
    $('#midnight-countdown').countdown({until: getMidnightCountDown(),
        serverSync: serverTime, format: 'HMS',
        onExpiry: function() {
            $(this).countdown('change', {until: getMidnightCountDown()});
        }});

function getNoonCountDown() {
    var until = new Date();
    until.setHours(until.getHours() < 12 ? 12 : 36, 0, 0, 0); // Next midday
    return until;
}

function getMidnightCountDown() {
    var until = new Date();
    until.setHours(24, 0, 0, 0); // Next midnight
    return until;
}
```